# dynamically scan accessed files, or modifed files with AV

Tags: bash, find, rhel, mcafee

I need to set up McAfee AV for Linux to either dynamically scan accessed files, or to perform daily scans on all modified files.

I know how to make a cron job, and to search for last modified files, but I can't find any documentation anywhere on how to do what I need to do, even from McAfee :(

The problem with scanning modified files is that I can't find any find options that will scan the modified files from the last scan date, only from a time-frame. If I set McAfee to scan modified files daily, and the machine is off for over a day, it wont see those modified files as being modified within 24hours, and thus won't scan them. I also cannot figure out how to make McAfee scan a while when it is accessed. I assume I could possibly write a script that just launches a scan when any file is opened, but I am not sure how to do this either.

If possible, I'd like to use bash to do this, only because I haven't learned awk or perl yet. Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with ClamAV, replace 'clamscan' with the equivalent command provided by McAfee. This loop will look for files in the /root directory that have been edited in the last 2 days and then run a virus scan on them:

```
for i in `find /root -type f -mtime -2`; do
  clamscan $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the use of the for loop in this example. Any idea how to make it scan a file once it's opened?

Comment: Take a look at iNotify, it can watch files/directories and trigger actions on a number of different events